# Getting every span within a table row using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a function which gets a tables rows by id, I would then like to get every span within each row, these will have a class of 'total-span' and do something with them.
The bit I'm having trouble with is getting the spans by class once I have the row.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Thanks

```
function fieldTotals() {
    var calculatedFields = document.getElementsByClassName("field-total");
    Array.from(calculatedFields).forEach((el) => {
        var _id = el.id;
        var _rows = document.getElementById("electric-totals-" + _id);

        //this next bit is what I can't get to work 
        Array.from(_rows).forEach((item) => {
            var _spans = $(item).find(".total-span"); //something like this?
            // then for each span get the int val of the innerHtml and sum them
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: if I could see the html it was easier .. but did you consider something like this:  `row.querySelectorAll('span.total-span')` ? where row is a tr HTMLElement fetched from DOM

Comment: `$(_row).find(".total-span")`

Comment: Thanks for the replies.  I think both your suggestions would work, it's the 'forEach' part, doing it for row in _rows (updated post)

Comment: I would just loop through _rows directly like: `_rows.forEach` but the way you fetched the rows is wrong! because the id is unique in the document. You can't have multiple rows with the same id and expect getElementById to return a list of elements. You should use a different selector like `#tableid tr` to fetch the rows belonging to the table having the id `tableid` (as long as you didn't use thead/tbody)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `querySelectorAll` on the row and get all the span elements. Then use the `reduce` function to compute the sum.

```
Array.from(_rows).forEach((item) => {
    let _spans = item.querySelectorAll('.total-span');
    if ( _spans == null ) return; 
    let sum = Array.from(_spans).reduce((sum, span) => sum + parseInt( span.innerHTML ), 0);
});
```